# Pulling AWS EC2 container results in "image no found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

**TL;DR** Can't pull an instance off of AWS's EC2

I created a WordPress instance on EC2 and would like to pull it local to work on. I followed [these directions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-pull-ecr-image.html), attached the [AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html) to my user, [Authenticated the registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth), but when I try to pull using the *repositoryUri* from **aws ecr describe-repositories** I get "error image [imagename] not found"

Also: In the AWS console, the public dns ends with us-west-**1**.compute.amazonaws.com, while the *repositoryUri* ends with dkr.ecr.us-west-**2**.amazonaws.com/ I don't know why *repositoryUri* has us-west-2

Also: This container is a copy. I created the original in US East and copying it to US West was easier than moving it.

Also: I'm on my work computer. Maybe the company security policy is interfering?

I'm running docker inside a Ubuntu VirtualBox. A fresh install via apt-get

```
Client:
Version: 1.12.6
API version: 1.24
Go version: go1.6.2
Git commit: 78d1802
Built: Tue Jan 31 23:35:14 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Server:
Version: 1.12.6
API version: 1.24
Go version: go1.6.2
Git commit: 78d1802
Built: Tue Jan 31 23:35:14 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
```

Comment: Did you push it to the registry (ECR) before pulling it?

Comment: On your suggestion I tried that. Same error.

Comment: Did you log in with the right region when you ran `aws ecr get-login --region <region>`? I would try to run the `docker login` command with a different region as it seems you have issues with regions.

Comment: Good idea. I also think the regions are messed up somehow. Logging in back and forth didn't work. I even made a copy on us-west-2. I think I'm going to try the other way around. Make a local container and upload that to EC2. Thanks for your help.